# bmp texture not loading correctly using Open GL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, textures

Hello everyone I'm trying to load a texture (normal map) using OpenGL.

```cpp
GLuint loadTexture(const char* fileName) {
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    // load file - using core SDL library
    SDL_Surface* tmpSurface;
    tmpSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(fileName);
    if (tmpSurface == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Error loading bitmap" << std::endl;
    }

    // bind texture and set parameters
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, tmpSurface->w, tmpSurface->h, 0,
        GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tmpSurface->pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    SDL_FreeSurface(tmpSurface);
    return textureID;
}
```

then if I try to render it, it gives me that :
[image]

Instead of :

[image]

But I can render this normaly :
[image]

Do you have an idea  ? color deep is 32 for the one that is not working and 24 for the working one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat) to convert the surface format and load the converted curface:

```
SDL_Surface* tmpSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(fileName);
SDL_Surface* formattedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(
                                tmpSurface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888, 0);
SDL_FreeSurface(tmpSurface);

// [...]

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, tmpSurface->w, tmpSurface->h, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, formattedSurface->pixels);
SDL_FreeSurface(formattedSurface);
```

Of course you can evaluate the `format` attribute of the [`SDL_Surface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) and set a proper format attribute when two-dimensional texture image is specified by [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml).

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, it works better but know everything looks red

Comment: everything turns blue, oh i should find the right order ?

Comment: @axelaxel I suggest `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888`

Comment: You saved me ! Thank you a lot